# Crear registros automáticamente en una tabla, cuando estoy agregando un registro en otra mediante Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, transacciones

Buen día compañeros, estoy comenzando a aprender SQL y me encontre con la siguiente situación:

Tengo 3 tablas:  "cuenta", "mes" e "historial_transacciones", la relacion que exite entre "mes" y "cuenta" es de "muchos a muchos".

Ahora, al crear un nuevo registro en la tabla "mes", justo al mismo tiempo, debo crear automaticamente registros en la tabla "historial_transacciones", pero la situacion es que cada registro de la tabla "historial_transacciones", debe estar relacionado respectivamente con otros registros ya existentes en la tabla "cuenta"

Ilustrare la situación de la siguiente manera:

1) Aqui les presento la tabla "cuenta", la cual posee ya 2 registros existentes, tal y como se muestra a continuación:

```
id_cuenta |  nombre_cuenta     | 
----------+--------------------+
    1     | Ahorro corriente   |  
    2     | Plazo Fijo         |
```

2) Ahora les presento la tabla "mes", en la cual estoy creando un nuevo registro, el cual es "Enero/2019" y tiene como id_mes "1"

```
id_mes| nombre_mes |  fecha_inicial  | fecha_final  | 
------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
1     | Enero/2019 |   2019-01-01    |  2019-01-31  |
```

3) Ahora les presento la tabla "historial_transacciones", y la situación es que al yo crear un nuevo mes, necesito que automaticamente se creen nuevos registros en la tabla "historial_transacciones"; mas especificamente hablando, un nuevo registro por cada registro ya existente en la tabla "cuenta", tendria que quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
id_historial_transacciones  |  id_mes |  id_cuenta |
----------------------------|---------+------------+
    1                       | 1       |    1       |
    2                       | 1       |    2       |
```

como se puede notar, se crearon 2 registros en la tabla "historial_transacciones", ambos relacionados con el nuevo mes creado, con la diferencia de que cada uno de estos registros va estar relacionado con cada registro ya existente en la tabla "cuenta".

He escuchado de que esto se puede resolver utilizando transact-SQL, sin embargo, este concepto es nuevo para mi, por lo cual agradeceria mucho la ayuda.

Nota: cada tabla obviamente tiene mas atributos, sin embargo solamente incluí los atributos necesarios.

Answer (score 1):

Mencionas dos veces Transact-Sql, y el código que te han proporcionado es para MySql, que no es del mismo modo. TSQL es el correspondiente a la base de datos de Microsoft SQL Server. Si estas utilizando este, entonces la respuesta puede ser tal que:

Me aprovecho del trabajo realizado por David Jp

```
CREATE TABLE cuenta(
 id_cuenta int identity PRIMARY KEY,
 nombre_cuenta varchar(31)
);
CREATE TABLE mes(
 id_mes int identity PRIMARY KEY,
 nombre_mes varchar(31),
 fecha_inicial date,
 fecha_final date
);
CREATE TABLE historial_transacciones(
id_historial_transacciones int identity PRIMARY KEY,
id_mes int,
id_cuenta int,
FOREIGN KEY(id_mes) REFERENCES mes(id_mes),
FOREIGN KEY(id_cuenta) REFERENCES cuenta(id_cuenta)
);
GO
INSERT INTO cuenta (nombre_cuenta) VALUES
 ('Ahorro corriente'),('Plazo fijo');
GO
```

Con esto el escenario es igual, a excepción de que en Sql Server no existe auto-increment, sino Identity.

El trigger es un poco diferente en su sintáxis:

```
CREATE TRIGGER nuevo_mes on dbo.mes 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO historial_transacciones (id_mes, id_cuenta)
    SELECT I.id_mes, CUENTA.id_cuenta
 FROM INSERTED I CROSS JOIN cuenta


 COMMIT TRAN; -- TODO CORRECTO, CONFIRMARMOS
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  
           @ErrorSeverity,
           @ErrorState 
           );  
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 )
        ROLLBACK TRAN; --DESHACEMOS LA TRANSACCIÓN
END CATCH
GO
```

Aquí si cambia un poco la cosa. Lo primero es que en Sql Server el objeto que contiene la fila/s que se estan insertando es la pseudo-tabla inserted. Para el desarrollo es exactamente igual que la tabla mes, pero no se puede modificar su contenido, y si se puede leer y relacionar con cualquier otra tabla.
Te he incluido un código de gestión de errores. Si ocurre algo dentro del trigger, que aborte la transacción y te de salida de lo que ha ocurrido. Por el contrario si todo va bien, confirme la misma.

En cuanto a inserted, observarás que realizamos un CROSS JOIN con cuenta. POr tanto cada fila que le llegue a inserted (que este insertandose en mes), realizará un producto cartesiano con todas las filas que existan en cuenta e insertará en histórico  una por cada.

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO MES (nombre_mes, fecha_inicial, fecha_final)
VALUES
('Enero/2019','20190101','20190131');
GO

INSERT INTO MES (nombre_mes, fecha_inicial, fecha_final)
VALUES
('Febrero/2019','20190201','20190228'),
('Marzo/2019','20190301','20190331');
GO
INSERT INTO cuenta (nombre_cuenta) VALUES
  ('Otro tipo');
GO
INSERT INTO MES (nombre_mes, fecha_inicial, fecha_final)
VALUES
('Abril/2019','20190401','20190430');
```

Hemos insertado un registro, varios, y uno de cuentas. El resultado es:

[image: Salida resultados]

Dos menciones aparte.

- No se controla, el historial, para registros que no tuvieran cuenta en meses anteriores.
- Las fechas se utilizan en el estandard Ansi yyyyMMdd, así independientemente de tu conexión, del lenguaje, estas se insertan correctamente

Te dejo un enlace, por si tienes dudas con cross join, que te puede resultar interesante.

[Cross join Repetir algo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/17/intervalos-de-numeros-o-repetir-algo-muchas-veces/)

Comment: Mira qué bien, así está también en SQL Server y con el plus de implementar una transacción financiera, mediante una transacción en lenguaje transaccional, rizando el rizo :) Un placer haberte dado el pie

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, estaría bien diferenciar tus transacciones, transacciones en informática y el SQL transaccional, que son cosas diferentes:

- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transacci%C3%B3n_financiera
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transacci%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL

a) Las transacciones que reflejas en tu tabla se refieren a operaciones bancarias o transacciones financieras

b) Una transacción en informática es un algoritmo compuesto de varios pasos que se han de aplicar uno después del otro y deben realizarse de una sola vez. Es decir, si uno de los pasos falla, deben deshacerse todos los pasos anteriores, de forma que dejen la base de datos en el mismo estado en el que estaba antes de empezar.

c) El SQL transaccional o programático es una extensión del SQL que permite hacer uso de procedimientos almacenados, disparadores y eventos. Más o menos poder programar en SQL.

Lo que parece que necesitas es un disparador. O sea, un procedimiento almacenado latente que se inicie cuando realices la inserción de un dato en la tabla mes. En el manual de MySQL tienes las instruccioes para crearlo: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html

```
CREATE TABLE cuenta(
  id_cuenta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_cuenta varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE mes(
  id_mes int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_mes varchar(31),
  fecha_inicial date,
  fecha_final date
  );
CREATE TABLE historial_transacciones(
  id_historial_transacciones int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_mes int,
  id_cuenta int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_mes) REFERENCES mes(id_mes),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_cuenta) REFERENCES cuenta(id_cuenta)
  );
INSERT INTO cuenta (nombre_cuenta) VALUES
  ('Ahorro corriente'),('Plazo fijo');
CREATE TRIGGER nuevo_mes AFTER INSERT ON mes
  FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO historial_transacciones (id_mes, id_cuenta)
      SELECT NEW.id_mes,id_cuenta FROM cuenta;
INSERT INTO mes (nombre_mes, fecha_inicial, fecha_final) VALUES
  ('Enero/2019','2019-01-01','2019-12-31');
```

Tras ejecutar todas las querys, obtendrás este resultado en la tabla `historial_transacciones`:

> ```
> ==================================
> |id_histori|  id_mes  |id_cuenta |
> |al_transac|          |          |
> |  ciones  |          |          |
> ==================================
> |    1     |    1     |    1     |
> ----------------------------------
> |    2     |    1     |    2     |
> ----------------------------------
> ```